# not able to access playstore after factory reset

Tags: google-play-store, samsung

I am not able to access the Google Play Store on my Samsung Galaxy Y GT-S5360 after a factory reset. How can I get it working again?

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to be a bit more detailed? What happens when you try to open the Play Store?

Comment: it just freezes and goes back to home screen. Also a message comes after a while saying google play store has unexpectedly stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a factory reset again, and don't include you gmail e-mail during setup i.e before the home screen comes, once the home screen is active then go to google play and login, should be able to download the apps

Comment: @Tephanie If it doesn't work, is there a reason why you accepted the answer?

Comment: @dotVezz i am new at this

Comment: @Tephanie No worries! And welcome to the site!